# RC_FILE don't work with QCoreApplication::applicationVersion when using MingW

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qt5

I create a simple rc file and put in `.pro`:

- `rcexample.rc`

  ```
  #include "winver.h"

  VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
      FILEVERSION 1,0,0,1
      PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,1
      FILEFLAGS 0x0L
      FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
      FILEOS 0x00040004L
      FILETYPE 0x1L
      FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
  BEGIN
      BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
      BEGIN
          BLOCK "000004b0"
          BEGIN
              VALUE "CompanyName", "Foo Bar CompanyName"
              VALUE "FileDescription", "Foo bar FileDescription"
              VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.1"
              VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Foo bar LegalCopyright"
              VALUE "InternalName", "foobar"
              VALUE "OriginalFilename", "foobar.exe"
              VALUE "ProductName", "foobar product name"
              VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0.1"
          END
      END
      BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
      BEGIN
          VALUE "Translation", 0x0, 1200
      END
  END
  ```
- `winvertest.pro`

  ```
  QT += core gui

  greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

  TARGET = winvertest
  TEMPLATE = app

  win32:RC_FILE = rcexample.rc # my rc file

  DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

  SOURCES += main.cpp
  ```
- `main.cpp`

  ```
  #include <QDebug>
  #include <QApplication>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      QApplication a(argc, argv);

      qDebug() << "applicationVersion:" << a.applicationVersion();

      return a.exec();
  }
  ```

Using *MSVC2015 32bit*, `applicationVersion` returns:

> applicationVersion: "1.0.0.1"

But using *Mingw 5.3.0* returns empty:

> applicationVersion: ""

Is this a Mingw issue or Qt issue or did I forget to add something to the "pro"?

Comment: Certain versions of resource compiler won't translate `VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0.1"` correctly without forcing end of string zero like  `VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0.1\0"`. Unsure whether or not that is the case.

Comment: @AlexanderVX thanks, but not work. From what I tested the `QCoreApplication::applicationVersion` takes the value from `PRODUCTVERSION`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably define your version numbers somewhere else and use those definitions in the .rc file. I use a header file for this, `src/appversion.h`, and it contains:

```
#define MY_APP_VERSION "1.1.0"
/* MS Windows executable resource versions. */
#define W32_RC_FILEVERSION 1,1,0,00
#define W32_RC_PRODUCTVERSION 1,1,0,00
```

I then use these definitions in my .rc file:

```
#include "src/appversion.h"

/* ... */

FILEVERSION W32_RC_FILEVERSION
PRODUCTVERSION W32_RC_PRODUCTVERSION
FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL

/* ... */
VALUE "FileVersion", MY_APP_VERSION
/* ... */
```

Then, after I instantiate a QApplication, I set the values like this:

```
a.setApplicationName(QString::fromLatin1("My App"));
a.setApplicationVersion(QString::fromLatin1(MY_APP_VERSION));
```

Comment: Great answer, but I still don't understand why not the difference of *MSVC* and *Mingw*. But I'm already using your suggestion +1

Comment: What causes I got "error: RC1020: unexpected '#endif'" when I include `version.h`？I am using qtcreator and put the .rc file in the .pro file.

Comment: @Crawl.W You cannot put the contents of an `.rc` file in the `.pro` file.

Comment: Maybe I'm not being precise enough,the way I use it is the same as in the topic.Would I send you my details?

Comment: using `#pragma once` rather than header guard can avoid this issue,don't know why.